# Is there a way to compare two cells in a Column in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I have rdlc report column that can contains duplicate value. Like

```
          Refno      value
cell1     c101       171.20
cell2     c102       150.20
cell3     c101       171.20
cell4     c101       171.20
cell5     c102       150.20
```

Now i want to compare every cell one by one with one another in the column Refno. Say at first I Will take cell1 value 'c101' and compare it through every other cell in Refno column to check is there another 'c101'. Can I do it in RDLC?

Comment: what is the result you're trying to achieve?, there is a posibility to access other rows in rdlc but this is usually something that sould be done on query/datamodel level. but if you just want to filter, there is a filter property in the tablix, you could also group by refno and delete the detail rows

Comment: Actually I want to sum value of distinct Refno. In Refno I have only two Distinct item 'c101' and 'c102' . I want to sum respective value of that two item that will give me result (171.20+150.20) only.  Currently I'm getting (171.20+150.20+171.20+171.20+150.20). 
@Bacon

Comment: In my case it is not possible in query/datamodel level. I tried with grouping too. But can't help myself getting a solution. I'm novice in rdlc. If somehow i can get my desired result that I describe in my previous comment, please kindly help me. @Bacon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a click sequence for sumrows in reports (hope it helps)

first you group by Refno

[image: first you group by Refno]

add a header or footer row

[image: add a header or footer row]

click on row visibility of the details row, i marked the logo with a red circle

[image: click on row visibility of the details row, i marked the logo with a red circle]

set it to hidden

[image: set it to hidden]

now you can use the sum function in the header/footer row

as result you only have as many rows as refno values

for your special case you need something like the following code inside the code pane

```
Public Shared table As System.Collections.Hashtable

Public Shared Function current(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
    If table Is Nothing Then
        table = New System.Collections.Hashtable()
    End If

    If table.ContainsKey(key) Then Return 0D
    table.Add(key, value)
    Return value
End Function
```

and use

```
=sum(Code.current(Fields!NewColumn0.Value,cdec(Fields!NewColumn1.Value)))
```

in the field where you want the sum

Comment: This doesn't work man. :-( I tried it earlier. And tried it now after your comment. @Bacon

Comment: what about it doesnt work? reports can be picky beasts and when it doesnt work it helps to test the singe steps.

Comment: When I hide, it hide the value. but in the time of sum, it sum all cells including hidden field value. @Bacon

Comment: i thought you want a sum, when you only want the first value theres the first() function

Comment: ```
=Sum(First(Fields!realval.Value, "Group1"))
```
Is it possible? @Bacon

Comment: unfortionately not sumfirst is not possible and reportingtools dont offer much for that problem, maybe theres a possibility for the dataset to filter duplicates, what datasource are you using?

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use a query like this

```sql
select sum (distinct Refno)from tablename
```

which will not show repetition for the column refno

Comment: Actually I'm filtering data with another filed. And I need that filtering. So I can't select my data by distinct Refno. @marcelo

Comment: Please add some more information like between which colmun u r comparing..etc